# Configure continuous client server socket with netty?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, client-server, netty

I'm using Netty v 4.1 with Java 8 to build a server application.
When the client sends a message, my server accepts the connection, then hands processing off to a new thread which terminates after replying over the existing connection. Netty then seems to close the connection.

What I want is for Netty to nail up a continuous connection between client and server so that multiple messages can be processed over the same connection.

Unfortunately, my search for examples of this has been fruitless. The Netty documentation seems to assume greater networking knowledge than I possess, since I've been unable to find even a hint there.

Any suggestions on how I can establish a continuous socket in this scenario?

Comment: Could you give us some code?

Answer (score 0):

After poring through the code again, I found a point where I'm closing the context.